# SonarQube server not showing in browser

Tags: sonarqube, virtual-machine, rhel

I have a Linux VM running with a Jenkins, Nexus and SonarQube server on it. The IP for the VM is 192.168.56.2 and I have no trouble accessing both Jenkins and Nexus on ports 8080 and 8081 respectively. However, when I try to access 192.168.56.2:9000 for SonarQube it just says *192.168.56.2 refused to connect*.

When I run `systemctl status sonar` in the terminal it shows that SonarQube is active and running. I have opened the firewall to port 9000 and I have not changed any of the default settings. Does anyone have any idea what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube will only be listening on 'loopback' rather than on all inbound IP addresses. In your server's sonar.properties file, you'll need to set the `Web` information in order to access the server remotely, specifically the following values:

```
sonar.web.host: 192.168.56.2
sonar.web.port: 80 # if you want to use a port other than 9000
```

Also, in the web UI's Settings, under the "General" section, set the "Server base URL" value so that links and redirects issued by SonarQube target the correct location.

Comment: I have also tried specifically setting the IP and port values in the properties file, but it made no difference.

Comment: Does it respond to a telnet/curl/wget from on the 192.168.56.2 host?